# Why can't I display my text with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've inherited this Laravel PHP app with some Javascript and I'm learning these 
.technologies as I work to enhance it. I've got this bit of code that I need to change, but I really don't understand it. Any help you can give to solve my problem and improve my understanding would be most welcome.

The code in question is executed when a `<div>` `#tweetContainer`, a class defined in the CSS. on a web page is clicked. As it stands, the code presents a pop-up with the text from the `<div>`. I want to change it so that it uses the string `post.data`.

I don't understand what the statements after the `{` are. I've tried replacing the first one with various forms of `post.data` but haven't got anything to work.

```
      $("#itemContainer .listview_tile:last").click(function(){
          $("#tweetContainer").val($(this).text());
          $("#loading").toggleClass('displayTable');
         $("#loading").fadeTo("fast", 0.95);
    });
```

The `click()` function appears to be part of Jquery.
Why does this work and what can I do to make it do what I need?

Comment: where is your `post.data`/`data.post` declared?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: `post.data` (sorry) is declared in the same function as the code I've shared. It contains a subset of the text in `itemContainer ` that I want to display on the next screen.

Comment: @Jeremy No, the app runs clean with nothing on the console.

Comment: "Why does this work and what can you do to ......?"  The last sentence ends abruptly.  If you click the "edit" link under your question you can fix it.

Comment: Can you post some code that shows what types of elements these are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As it stands, the code presents a pop-up with the text from the . I want to change it so that it uses the string post.data.

If I understand correctly, you want the value of `post.data` to be set as the text of `#tweetContainer`.

You need to use this :

```
$('#tweetContainer').text(post.data);
```

`val()` is use to set and get the value attribute of an element, if you want to change the content of a `div` for example, you need to use `text()` .

Answer (score 0):

What does this code do?

```
  $("#itemContainer .listview_tile:last")//see below
   .click(function(){// when you click
      //**this** is span.listview_tile
      //its text comes to <input id="tweetContainer" />
      $("#tweetContainer").val($(this).text());
      //add / remove class displayTable 
      $("#loading").toggleClass('displayTable');
      //show with fadeTo effect 
     $("#loading").fadeTo("fast", 0.95);
});               

<div id="itemContainer ">
   <span class="listview_tile">one</span>
   <span class="listview_tile">two</span><!--$("#itemContainer .listview_tile:last") -->
   <input type="text" id="tweetContainer" />
</div>
<div id="loading">Loading something</div>
```

I hope this explanations help you.